# Наследование в CSS

Tags: html, css

Как можно отменить наследование родительских элементов для CSS? У меня одно меню в другом и они конфликтуют постоянно.

```
#birinci_menu li a {
display: block;
color: #464646;
padding: 0 15px;
line-height: 34px;
border-left: 1px solid silver;
font-size: 10pt;
font-family: arial;
}
#menu_1, #menu_2 {
padding: 0px 25px;
}
```

*#birinci_menu li a* - родитель, он замещает собой паддинг для внутреннего меню
в итоге на элементе падинг 15 px

Comment: Да там, удалите 3 строку во втором файле css.

Comment: Код в студию.

Comment: добавил код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй сделать не идентификатор, а  класс, наподобие:
.myClass {
padding: 0px 25px;
}